# How can I most cleanly use Roxygen2 to document a vector in R

Tags: r, roxygen2, roxygen

I am writing a package and use Roxygen2 to build the documentation inside the source files (and pkgdown to render them as a website).

I have all the key exported functions documented - so far so good.

However the package has a number of publicly exported named-item list vectors containing objects which I'd like to document.

I could place the code at the top as with the functions - but if the list or the objects created within the list are complex (which mine can be - some are list of quosures for example for use with a shiny dashboard), then it means that the documentation and code can easily go out of sync.

Ideally I'd like to write the documentation inline to the object I'm are documenting - ie. intersperse the list with comment lines which are then assembled into the final document.

Could anyone suggest any neat ways to do this? Or a working pattern which might help with this? Sort of:

```
#' Filter list for MyAwesomeShinyApp
#' 
#' Creates a set of filter actions as quosures. The quosures should
#' be inserted into our dplyr::filter query using quasiquotation.
#' The available filters are as follows:
#'
#' @export
myListOfFilters <- list(

  #' first_filter sets up a really complicated filter using a function
  #' based on the dog's favourite toy.
  "first_filter" = reallyComplexFunction(dog, dogToy),

  #' second_filter only looks up dogs called Fido.
  "second_filter" = rlang::quo(.data[["DogName"]] == "Fido")
)
```

You can see in this example how in-line documentation of each item in the list makes more sense as the list size scales. Clearly this example doesn't work! Question is - is there a way of working which permits similar to this?